# How to manage users/passwords in devstack?

Tags: openstack, devstack

I've installed [devstack](http://devstack.org/) to a clean Ubuntu machine. I'm able to access the OpenStack Dashboard at `http://localhost/auth/login/`. However, I have no idea how to manage users or what my initial credentials are.

Where is this information is kept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information is kept in the Keystone MySQL database. Do not edit the DB directly!

You'll want to manage users via the Keystone CLI. To do this you need to source your DevStack admin creds properly.

```
cd devstack
source openrc admin admin
echo $OS_USERNAME
echo $OS_TENANT_NAME
echo $OS_PASSWORD
```

I put the echo commands there to show you how to discover your creds.

To use the Keystone CLI checkout the docs [Creating Tenants, Users, Roles, Tokens and Endpoints](http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-identity/admin/content/creating-tenants-users-roles-tokens-and-endpoints.html) and [Manage projects, users, and roles](http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide-admin/content/admin_cli_manage_projects_users.html).

If you want to work with the CLIs as a non-admin user just do

```
cd devstack
source openrc
echo $OS_USERNAME
echo $OS_TENANT_NAME
echo $OS_PASSWORD
```

Comment: The credentials don't work. Web panel keeps saying "An error occurred authenticating. Please try again later.". Where can I find the cause of this bug? Error logs?

Comment: Honestly, what I do in this situation is to just delete whatever I installed DevStack on and start over fresh. Don't bother trying to fix or troubleshoot it. I suggest using DevStack from a stable branch, see http://blog.phymata.com/2012/11/08/openstack-devstack-on-the-rackspace-open-cloud/ Replace folsom with havana everywhere in that post to get the latest and greatest OpenStack.